# converting an imagemagick command to rmagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I need a help with converting the following imagemagick command to rmagick. Any help or insight appreciated.

```
convert rose: -background black -gravity south -splice 0x8 \
          \( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 69,0 white' \) \
          \( +clone -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
          \( -clone 1 -level 25%,75% \
                 -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
                 +level 50%,0 \) \
          -delete 1 -swap 0,1  miff:- |\
     composite - -virtual-pixel black  -displace 17x7  rose_cylinder.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_cylinder

Basically there will be two images, one in the shape of cylinder say a mug and other image will be cylindrically placed on the mug shape.

Thanks.

Update:
This is the code that I am trying to build.

```
base_image = "/home/mon/ruby/images/cylinder.png" 
design_image = "/home/mon/ruby/images/design.png" 
bg = Magick::Image.read(base_image).first 
img = Magick::Image.new(500, 600) { 
  self.background_color = 'white' 
} 
img = img.composite bg, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp 
design = Magick::Image.read(design_image).first 
design.background_color = 'transparent' 
design.gravity = SouthGravity 
design = design.splice("0x8") 
design1 = design.clone.sparse_color(Magick::BarycentricColorInterpolate, 0, 0, "black", 69, 0, "white") 
design2 = design1.clone.function_channel Magick::ArcsinFunction, 0.5
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mudasobwa I am trying to use the above imagemagick command to Rmagick syntax. I am new to rmagick, so any help with the conversion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @shelvacu Since I am new to rmagick, I have tried to follow the documentation of rmagick, and trying to convert the above code to rmagick. I have converted some of the steps, but not getting any headway further.

Comment: base_image = "/home/mon/ruby/images/cylinder.png"
design_image = "/home/mon/ruby/images/design.png"

bg = Magick::Image.read(base_image).first

img = Magick::Image.new(500, 600) {
     self.background_color = 'white'
    }
img = img.composite bg, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp
design = Magick::Image.read(base_image).first
design.background_color = 'transparent'
design.gravity = SouthGravity
design = design.splice("0x8")
design1 = design.clone.sparse_color(Magick::BarycentricColorInterpolate, 0, 0, "black", 69, 0, "white")
design2 = design1.clone.function_channel Magick::ArcsinFunction, 0.5

Comment: @MontyS your code is difficult to read when you paste it without ormatting into a comment. By the way, why do you want to translate the ImageMagick command? You can call the command verbatim from Ruby using backticks.

Comment: @maxpleaner pardon me, this is the first time I am using the interface, will try to make it more readable. I am trying to make it in rmagick to make it more readable and maintainable. If you could help me in converting it to rmagick it would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: @MontyS understandable. You should add your attempt code into the question, though. Also mention how your attempt is failing. In general, folks on this site aren't going to want to just _write code for X_. They want to help you solve a specific question.

Comment: @maxpleaner I have added the code that I started with, I have a big issue which I did not see anywhere in documentation, how do I implement           "-clone" . Also this code I am not able to understand how it will be converted to rmagick. -delete 1 -swap 0,1  miff:- |\
     composite - -virtual-pixel black  -displace 17x7